# Prioritize optional line breaks in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, line-breaks

HTML5 has some great tools for controlling optional line breaks: line break opportunity `<wbr>`, non-breaking space `&nbsp;`, soft break `&shy;`, and zero-width space `&#8203;`. As far as I can tell, optional line breaks always occurs closest to where the line would overflow (on the right for left-to-right languages). But what if I'd prefer for optional breaks to start on the left?

Here's an example. Three ways of writing it take one line if there's room.

```
Noise. Signal→Exit            // A
Noise. Signal<wbr>→Exit       // B
Noise.<wbr> Signal<wbr>→Exit  // C
```

[image: "Noise. Signal→Exit" on one line]

If "Noise. Signal→Exit" breaks in one place, I want the break to happen after `.`. Approach A succeeds, where approaches B and C fail.

￼
[image: With one break]

If it breaks at two places, I want it to break at before `→`. Approach A fails, where B and C succeed.

[image: With two breaks]

Each option fails sometimes; I can't great the break behavior I want in all circumstances. But perhaps I’m missing something. How can I be more specific about when I where and when breaks to occur?

Comment: can you include the code you are having issues with? I am not sure I follow

Comment: It's there at the top (in markdown).

Comment: So is the issue with Markdown or HTML?

Comment: This Markdown compiles to HTML. The issue is with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the part of the text you want to stay together (including the `<wbr>`) in a `<span>` that sets `display: inline-block`.

Your code would be:
`Noise.<wbr><span>Signal<wbr>→Exit</span>`

As can be seen in the following:

```css
.one {
  width: 150px;
}

.two {
  width: 100px;
}

.three {
  width: 50px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Noise.<wbr><span>Signal<wbr>→Exit</span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="two">
  Noise.<wbr><span>Signal<wbr>→Exit</span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="three">
  Noise.<wbr><span>Signal<wbr>→Exit</span>
</div>
```